# gapi.auth2.BasicProfile.getName is not a function / How to sue BasicProfile of Google API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to the user's name after they have authenticated. However I get the error:
gapi.auth2.BasicProfile.getName is not a function

Anybody got a working example for one of the BasicProfile methods.

```
// user authenticates then I run loadClient

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
function loadClient() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey("API_KEY");
  return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/analytics/v3/rest")
      .then(function() {
              console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
              addNameAndEmail();
            },
            function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}
// Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
function addNameAndEmail() {
  console.log( gapi.auth2.BasicProfile.getName() );
}
gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
  gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "CLIENT_ID"});
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.le.tt.Ad; This gives the name of user. You can test the object in chrome dev tools console.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article might help you

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people

Try using

```
function addNameAndEmail() {
  console.log( gapi.auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile().getName() );
}
```